# What are Constant cards?

Tags: neoverse

I'm not sure which types of cards are considered **Constant**.

Any examples or names of cards?

[image: Neoverse tooltip]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cards in Neoverse are divided into 4 categories: Attack, Defend, Constant & Instant.

You can open your deck by clicking the cards icon in the top right part of the screen to open a screen similar to this:
[image: Neoverse deck]
[src](https://www.thedigitalfix.com/gaming/review/neoverse-trinity-edition/)
On the left you can see the total number of cards you have for each type. Red is Attack, Blue is Defend, Yellow is Constant and finally Purple is Instant.